# Can't get response from returned Request in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I just want to pass url to another parser. It didn't work as shown in the doc so I've reduced my code to the minimum and still nothing. Tried with yield also

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import cfscrape
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
import json

rez=[]

class LinkbaseSpider(Spider):

name = "mine"
allowed_domains = ["127.0.0.1"]
start_urls = (
    'file://127.0.0.1/home/link.html',
) 

def parse(self, response):

    request= scrapy.Request("http://www.google.com",callback=self.parse2)
    return request


def parse2(self,response):
    self.logger.info("Visited %s", response.url)
    print("00000000000000000000000")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your indentation is actually correct, there is an `OffSiteMiddleware` that filters your requests based on `allowed_domains`. In this case `google.com` is not allowed because the `allowed_domains` are set to `["127.0.0.1"]`.

You can workaround it by setting [`dont_filter=True`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) when instantiating a `Request`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.Request("http://www.google.com",
                          callback=self.parse2,
                          dont_filter=True)
```

FYI, in case you are interested, here is how the middleware works internally: [source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/342cb622f1ea93268477da557099010bbd72529a/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py#L30).